# How to replace a key in a mongo document with the value of a variable

Tags: mongodb

```
const relation = love (the key in document is love)

await collection(coll).updateOne({_id: new ObjectId(id)},
    [ {$set: { "$$relacion":  1 }}])
```

I have tried = $relation $$relation "$relation" "$$relation"

Comment: Are you trying to change the field **name** or field **value**? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document

Comment: Try `db.collection.updateOne({ _id: id }, { $set: { [relation]: 1 } })`

Comment: im trying bind the value of const relation ("love") to query the field love in the document

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the **field value**, you can do it like this:

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    {_id: new ObjectId(id)},
    { $set: { 'username': 'Updated value' } },
    { upsert: true }
)
```

or

```
const user = await User.findById(id);
user.username = 'Updated value';
await user.save();
```

If you want to rename a **field name**, you can do it like this:

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: new ObjectId(id) },
    { $rename: { "Old field": "New field" } }
)
```

*Note that I used a User model, and this is just  an example*

Comment: What to do when there is no old field?